# Confused with two keywords: __name__ and __main__

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have gone through various post and explanations for the above keywords [`__name__` and `__main__`].

Please confirm if my understanding is Correct

1.`__name__` saves the name of the file automatically when a file is edited & saved.

2.`__main__` is updated through command prompt.

What is the value stored in `__main__` when its not initialized ?

Can I program the `__main__` to access the conditional code in the file?

For example, I have two files `a.py` and `b.py`

**a.py**

```
import b
# Can I program here '__main__' to access the functionality in b?
# So that I can print the condition is true if __name__ == '__main__':
```

**b.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'This program is being run by itself'    
else:
    print 'I am being imported from another module'
```

Please comment your views on understanding and Possibility of access/modifying `__main__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__name__` will give you the name of the current module and module which is used when you say

```
python prog.py
```

`__name__` in `prog.py` would now be `__main__`. This has been explained in python docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)

Comment: "__ name__ in prog.py would now be __ main__" is __ main__ automatically updated ?

Comment: `__main__` refers to the main module and `__name__` variable would give the name of the current module.

Comment: thank you for the docs link.. it help me in understanding

Comment: I am waiting for one more query. is it possible to manipulate the __ main__ ?

Comment: @user2598064 Nope. We cannot change `__main__` :(